# Changing "purchasable" in WooCommerce using REST API

Tags: rest, woocommerce

I am trying to update the "purchasable" flag on a product variation using REST API

```
/wp-json/wc/v3/products/<prodID>/variations/<varID>
```

I have tried sending a simple

```
{"purchasable":false}
```

as well as getting the current data for the variation, changing the "purchasable" entry to the new state, and submitting the entire data back to WooCommerce. In no case have I been able to change this value using REST API.

I am using jw-auth for authentication and have a proper token (I do receive a proper response back with all the data for the variation, but still with the old value of "purchasable" in it, so I know I'm communicating with the back-end).

Is there some setting elsewhere that needs to be set for me to be able to change this specific property? The variations have been created using REST API as well, and on the shop it works fine (I can pick the variations as expected).

What am I doing wrong? Or have I found a bug in WooCommerce? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That field is listed as ReadOnly in the api docs. I believe Woo uses other criteria to set that value.  In my research, it appears that setting the Stock Status to "outofstock" seems to be a common method for keeping an item from being purchased.  Also, setting the price to null or empty.
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#product-properties

Comment: Setting it "out of stock" means that you can still select the variation in the UI (but WC then shows an "out of stock" in red). I haven't tried with empty price - that might work to remove the possibility of selecting the variation entirely. The odd thing is that I can set this value using the web interface (it's the "enabled" property on the variation).

Comment: I haven't done anything with variations yet, so blanking the price may not yield the same results in that scenario compared to simple and bundled products like I'm working with.  I'm still learning about all of the ins and outs of Woo myself, but hopefully you'll be able to get past this issue.  Good luck!

Comment: Just to follow up: I have now implemented _regular_price_ = null when I want to disable the possibility of selecting that variation altogether, and it works. Only (small) caveat is that when you edit the item, you get a warning that there's one (or more) variations that don't have a price. If you ignore this warning, it works fine as an "enable"/"disable" option for a specific variation, now that you can't - programmatically - toggle the "enabled" checkbox that exist on the variation and is togglable in the web interface.